# Javascript find and replace function using while loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple function to find and replace text in my textarea **message**. User will be able to type into the textarea and also be able to find and replace words from the text area they just entered. Currently I'm trying to use a while loop to replace multiple same words found in the textarea that the user keyed in. But every time I run it it seems to freeze the entire html page any idea why this is happening?

**find** and **replace** are textbox for user to key in the word they want to find and replace the user is able to key in multiple words to replace as well.

```js
function findText() {
  let find = document.getElementById('find').value;
  let replace = document.getElementById('replace').value;
  let message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var lmao = message.indexOf(find);

  while (message.indexOf(find) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("message").value = message.replace(find, replace);
  }
}
```

Comment: does the message variable change inside of the loop?

Comment: why you use var for lmo?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `while` loop with a `replaceAll`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

```js
function findText() {

  let find = document.getElementById('find').value;
  let replace = document.getElementById('replace').value;
  let message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var lmao = message.indexOf(find);

  document.getElementById("message").value = message.replaceAll(find, replace);

}
```

```html
<div>Find <input id="find" value="find" /></div>
<div>Replace <input id="replace" value="replace" /></div>
<div>
  <textarea id="message" style="height: 100px">you can find and replace every words just by .replaceAll, example: find 1 find 2 find 3</textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="findText()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But the problem with this solution is that it will find all word that has the same letters i search on the find button, e.g if I search for 'ou' it will replace the letters inside the word 'you'.

Answer (score 0):

Just a addition in other answer you can use `g` for global search and to replace where you find that word .
[Read more about regex and //g here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)

> Also you can let the search `case-insensitivity` using `i` along with `g` like this :
> `message.replace(/find/g, replace)`
> This way it will also replace **Find finD FIND**

And instead of using `while` you can use `if` loop

```js
function findText() {

  let find = document.getElementById('find').value;
  let replace = document.getElementById('replace').value;
  let message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var lmao = message.indexOf(find);

  if(message.indexOf(find) != -1) {

    document.getElementById("message").value = message.replace(/find/g, replace);

  }

}
```

```html
<div>Find <input id="find" value="find" /></div>
<div>Replace <input id="replace" value="replace" /></div>
<div>
  <textarea id="message" style="height: 100px">you can find and replace every words just by .replaceAll, example: find 1 find 2 find 3</textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="findText()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `while` condition. When all input fields are empty your `while` condition is `true`. So inside the while condition the input value keeps on updating to empty string again, which makes loop an infinite loop. Thats why your ui is breaking.

**Issue Scenario**

```js
console.log(("").indexOf("") !== -1);
```

To fix this, you have to make sure that your `find` and `replace` values are not same. Or else, it will be an infinite loop again.

**Fixed Solution**

```js
function findText() {
  let find = document.getElementById('find').value;
  let replace = document.getElementById('replace').value;
  let message = document.getElementById('message');
  while (find !== replace && message.value.indexOf(find) != -1) {
    message.value = message.value.replace(find, replace);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="find">
<input type="text" id="replace">
<textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onclick="findText()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Yes but the issue is that only after i press the check button then the function will be executed, so wouldnt it only be affected if i left the textbox blank and run the function?